# Website images from Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Bit confused as to following is possible.

I have a working site at www.mywebsite.com on my VPS server

I have an images folder at www.mywebsite.com/images

I want to move my images directory to an s3 bucket and serve them from there but with following

1. Any web requests for mywebsite.com go to my VPS server
2. Any web requests for mywebsite.com/images pull from s3

The only way I can do this at the moment is by creating a CNAME and a sub domain IE myimages.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

Can this be done without a sub domain for images but allow the remainder of my site to stay on my VPS?

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is you want requests for mywebsite.com/images to go to s3 and not really your website without using a DNS entry such as CNAME then the answer is no. That is the only way.

/images is a HTTP request to a DNS resolved name. if your image URLs are living at mywebsite.com then the only way to get them to point to s3 is by a DNS entry, such as a cname in which you instead use images.mywebsite.com -> s3_URL.com/images

Comment: Ok thanks. I was hoping to do it without the sub domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using CloudFront.

1. Point your DNS `mywebsite.com` to a CloudFront distribution.
2. Setup a distribution behaviour such that `/images/*` is directed to an S3 bucket origin (containing your images)
3. Setup the default behaviour such that everything else is directed to your current VPS.